# antlr4 grammar to iteratively parse repeating things from a single InputStream

Tags: antlr4

I have an `InputStream` that contains repeating chunks like this:

```
fld1:val1
fld2:val2

[A B C D]
[E F]

fld1:val3
fld2:val4

[M N]
[Q S T Y]

fld1:val5
...
```

I wish to construct a solution where I can parse the `fld:val` block, skip the blank line separator, then parse the "listy" part, then stop parsing at the next blank line and reset the parser on the same open stream to process the next chunk.  I was thinking I might be able to do this in my override of the baselistener class `exitListy` callback by getting access to the parser and calling `reset()`.  Ideally, this would end the call chain to `ParseTree t = parser.parse()` and let control return to the code immediately following `parse()`  I experimented with this and, somewhat predictably, got a null pointer exception here: `org.antlr.v4.runtime.Parser.exitRule(Parser.java:639)`  I cannot change the format of the input stream, like inserting snip-here markers or anything like that.

Comment: @ggorlen It is not a "problem" I am experiencing; I am just looking for top level guidance / tricks on how such a construct could be made to work.   The specific rules for the chunks are not important and my grammar to consume them works fine.

Answer (score 1):

(Completely new answer based on comment)

Listeners operate on ParseTrees returned once a parse completes.  In your case, it appears, You'll be listening on an, essentially, unending stream, and want data back periodically.

I'd highly recommend "The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference" from Pragmatic Programmers.

There are two very pertinent sections:

- "Making Things Happen During the Parse"
- "Unbuffered Character and Token Streams"

For your grammar, try something akin to the following "rough draft" (this may not be reporting back exactly when you want, but hopefully gives you the idea to work with)

```
grammar Streaming;

@parser::members {
    java.util.function.Consumer<MyData> consumer;
    MyData myData = new MyData();
    public StreamingParser(TokenStream input, java.util.function.Consumer<MyData> consumer) {
        this(input);
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }
}

stream: (fldLine emptyLine listLine emptyLine) EOF;

fldLine:
    fld = ITEM COLON val = ITEM EOL {
    // add data to MyDataObject
};

listLine:
    O_BRACKET (items = ITEM)* C_BRACKET {
    // add data to MyDataObject
};

emptyLine:
    EOL {
    consumer.accept(myData);
    // reset myData
};

O_BRACKET: '[';
C_BRACKET: ']';
EOL: '\n';
COLON: ':';
ITEM: [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*;
SPACE: ' ' -> skip;
```

This takes advantage of embedded actions that are described in the first section.

Then the second section describes how to use Unbuffered streams.

Something like this (untested; much lifted directly from the referenced book)

```
CharStream input = new UnbufferedCharStream(<your stream>);
StreamingLexer lex = new StreamingLexer(input);
lex.setTokenFactory(new CommonTokenFactory(true));
TokenStream tokens = new UnbufferedTokenStream<CommonToken>(lex);
StreamingParser parser = new StreamingParser(tokens,
     // This lambda will handle data reported back when a blank line is encountered
     myData -> handle(myData));
// You just want ANTLR reporting back periodically
// not building a giant parse tree
parser.setBuildParseTree(false); 
parser.stream();  // won't return until you shut down the input stream
```

Comment: This is The Right solution if you want to parse 0 to n chunks in one shot.  But I don't want the parser to build a list of (fldblock listblock) pairs; for streams with millions of items it blows up the memory.   antlr keeps "sniffing ahead" on the stream.

Comment: Best part of your answer:  recommending I read,   ;-)    Thanks; this gives me new areas to explore that I did not know about.   Will code it up and see if it works completely.